# Problems Using CEX API in Python-- Cannot use module.

Tags: python, api, import, module

I am currently attempting to use the cex.io Python API for accessing financial data. Here is a link to github with the library: https://github.com/matveyco/cex.io-api-python

I installed it on MacOS X by using "python setup.py install" in Terminal. In the link above, it says to initialize the class we should use the following:

```
    import cexapi
    api = cexapi.api(username, api_key, api_secret)
```

However, when I put this code in a .py file in a directory without any other files, bash responds with:

```
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'api'
```

I am pretty sure the library is correctly installed (Python has no problem importing cexapi). It is clear to me that there is something about Python objects that I don't understand or I must have incorrectly installed the module.

Just in case it helps, I ran the following in the Python interpreter:

```
    import cexapi
    cexapi.__file__
```

And got the following:

```
    '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cexapi-0.1-py3.4.egg/cexapi/__init__.py'
```

This command should show where the module is stored. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I need to use this API. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use upper case letters:

```
import cexapi
api = cexapi.API(username, api_key, api_secret)
```

Comment: For those who struggle to see the difference, it's ".API" vs ".api".